# Error when using streaming_python in Pig

Tags: python, apache-pig

When I run the following:

```
REGISTER /home/hduser/Documents/ccc/Research/phd/code/ECentre/scripts/bags.py USING streaming_python 
AS bp;

raw = LOAD 'hdfs:///user/hduser/smsCorpus_en_2012.04.30_all.xml'   AS (line:chararray);


b = foreach raw generate bp.enumerate_bag(line);
```

I get

```
Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse: 
<file /home/hduser/Documents/ccc/Research/phd/code/ECentre/scripts/nltk.pig, line 13, column
25> Failed to generate logical plan. Nested exception: org.apache.pig.backend.executionengine.ExecException:
ERROR 1070: Could not resolve bp.enumerate_bag using imports: [, java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin.,
org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

bags.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
def enumerate_bag(input):
    output = []
    for rank, item in enumerate(input):
        output.append(tuple([rank] + list(item)))
    return output
```

Can anyone tell me why?

My version is:
Apache Pig version 0.12.2-SNAPSHOT (r: unknown) 
compiled Apr 29 2014, 13:40:45

Comment: Are those quotes actually in your python source?

Comment: No. The code was not displaying properly without them (or so I thought!)

Comment: Thanks, I removed them for you & formatted it :)